Large React Aria Components dropdown with virtualized rows
I need to implement a dropdown with react-aria-components but one of the use cases has a large amount of instances, provoking a very slow experience. For that reason, I want to use a row virtualization library. I tried with two (react-window and @tanstack/react-virtual) but in both cases it seems to be an issue with the popdown.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/eager-tdd-wz8x92
Here I have a simplification of the dropdown I need:

Without virtualization (using map to render items, because I would need to map the items when virtualizing).
Virtualizing with react-window.
Virtualizing with @tanstack/react-virtual.

Do you know what's provoking the problem? If you have a third option to virtualize rows, I could use another library if necessary, but using react-aria-components is a must.
